# Svelte typescript safe components

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to take components and its types, put it to single variable and then use it on page.

```js
import { Container_01 } from './components/containers';
import { Footer_01 } from './components/footers';
import type { Container01 } from '$types/containers/Container_01';
import type { Footer01 } from '$types/footers/Footer_01';

type UIKitType = {
    containers: {
        Container_01: Container01,
    };
    footers: {
        Footer_01: Footer01
    }
}

const UIKit = {
    containers: {
        Container_01: Container_01
    },
    footers: {
        Footer_01: Footer_01
    }
}


type ComponentTypes = {
    [K in keyof UIKitType]: {
        [L in keyof UIKitType[K]]:{
            type: K,
            component: L,
            props: UIKitType[K][L]
        }
    }[keyof UIKitType[K]]
}[keyof UIKitType]
```

Then when i use it in svelte page:

```html
{@const type = "containers"}
{@const component = "Container_01"}

<svelte:component
    this={UIKit[type][component]}

    props={data.props}
></svelte:component>
```

I got typescript error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type

I have no idea, how to solve it. Only thing i now its working without ts error is to use `[key: string]: UIComponent;`.